# wav recording stream extract volume number

Tags: c#, wav, volume

I have a `Stream` of audio data coming from my mic for which I would like to display the current recording volume level.  From what I've gathered, I need to store X number of bytes in an array and then I can use that data to process that one sample from the recording.  How do I determine what X is, and what do I need to do to get the volume level from that data?

I'm working in C# but even pseudo code would be very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WAV files are amplitude-modulated, so each sample value *is* the relative volume. Average across time and you get an average volume.

Things to watch out for:

- The above only applies to uncompressed LPCM data. WAV files can be compressed, in which case you'd need to implement whatever decoder is needed to get uncompressed data to work with.
- WAV files can be both 8-bit or 16-bit
- WAV files do have some header info to skip past, the file format is well-documented (https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)
- Watch your endians when reading the header

Here's some sample .NET code for reading WAV files:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/WaveEdit.aspx

Comment: Thanks!  I will take a look at the project.  I don't think that audio coming from the Mic will be compressed.  Is that a safe assumption?